# How to replace a column in .mat and locate the row of a date?

Tags: matlab

I have a .mat file like that:

> 727186  120.0000   92.0000       NaN       NaN   37.6000   ...
>
> 727187  168.0000   74.0000       NaN       NaN   38.0000   ...
>
> 737188  139.0000   80.0000       NaN       NaN   27.1000   ...
>
> 727191  139.0000   60.0000   23.0000  846.0000   30.1000   ...
>
> 727192  136.0000   72.0000   19.0000  175.0000   25.8000   ...
>
> ...

My questions are:

1. How to change the first column to a date format, like '2000/01/01'?
2. How to locate the row of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use datestr to convert the first column.  If you're looking to locate the row that a certain date occurs I'd try something like:

```
A = [727186 120.0000 92.0000 NaN NaN 37.6000; ...
727187 168.0000 74.0000 NaN NaN 38.0000; ...
737188 139.0000 80.0000 NaN NaN 27.1000; ...
727191 139.0000 60.0000 23.0000 846.0000 30.1000; ...
727192 136.0000 72.0000 19.0000 175.0000 25.8000];
x = strmatch('1990/12/20', cellstr(datestr(A(:,1),26)), 'exact')
x =
    2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!! it helps!! The Matlab says STRMATCH will be removed in the future release, and suggests use STRCMP instead. but I don't see how STRCMP could do the same thing? any suggestions?

Comment: Something like this will work as well.  Then just use the logical array II to index into your matrix, `A(II,:)` just takes one more step and maybe not as pleasing as a plain index.  `II = strcmp('1990/12/20',cellstr(datestr(A(:,1),26)))

II =

     0
     1
     0
     0
     0`